# Python API request POST does not pass parameters that contain "="

Tags: python, c#, api, request

I've been trying out an API call that contains content with the character "=". When I check the API content inside the C# API, the parameter with the "=" character is missing.

Theres also an issue with the "+" character, which simply disappears and gets replaced with " ". I've tried different encodings but the issue persists.

Do you have any idea where the issue might be?

```
import requests
import json

qry = "select SUM(this + that) as a from asd WHERE a = 10"

URL = "http://127.0.0.1:42100"
PARAMS = {'request_type':'translate_model', 
           'content_string': qry}
r = requests.post(url = URL, params = PARAMS)
```

In the example above the content_string parameter is not present in the C# API parameters.

Comment: `PARAMS` would get URL-encoded, look for something like: `select%20SUM(this%20%2B%20that)%20as%20a%20from%20asd%20WHERE%20a%20%3D%2010`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Adding `urllib.parse.quote_plus(qry)` fixed it.

Comment: Use following : "select SUM(this + that) as a from asd WHERE a &equals; 10"  You are sending as HTML and the equals sign is a special character.